Can't connect to MySQL server in Git-Hub Action
I installed MySQL 9.0 in the docker environment using mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1 [1] in GitHub Action. I set it up in Spring project as follows.
File application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: 1234
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
#        hbm2ddl.auto: create

When I uncomment the annotation part from this code, it didn't connect to mysql in github action. Why does that one line change the result?
[workflow]
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    permissions:
      contents: read
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build.yml

  test:
    permissions:
      contents: read
    uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yml

  dependency-submission:
    permissions:
      contents: write
    uses: ./.github/workflows/dependency-submission.yml

name: test

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
      - name: Set up MySQL
        uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1
        with:
          host port: 3306
          container port: 3306
          character set server: 'utf8mb4'
          collation server: 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
          mysql version: '9.0'
          mysql database: 'testdb'
          mysql user: 'root'
          mysql password: '1234'

      - name: Get MySQL container ID
        run: echo "::set-output name=container_id::$(docker ps -q -f ancestor=mysql:9.0)"
        id: container_id

      - name: Print MySQL version
        run: |
          docker exec -i ${{ steps.container_id.outputs.container_id }} 
          mysql -uroot -p1234 -e "SELECT VERSION();"

      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@v3

      - name: test with Gradle Wrapper
        run: ./gradlew test -s

[build.gradle]
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com.dnd'
version = '0.0.1'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:9.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    // P6spy
    implementation 'com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.9.0'

    // QueryDSL
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta"
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta"
    annotationProcessor "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api"
    annotationProcessor "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api"

    // Swagger
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

def querydslDir = layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/querydsl").get().asFile

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir querydslDir
}

clean {
    delete file("${querydslDir}")
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    clean
    options.getGeneratedSourceOutputDirectory().set(file(querydslDir))
}


When I tried to connect with Unix socket, I got the error message like
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
When I set IP as a 127.0.0.1 and tried to connect with TCP/IP, I got the error message like ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
When I set IP as a localhost and tried to connect with TCP/IP, I got the error message like ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)
The database name also matched. I tried all the other methods (TCP connection, permission setting, socket path check, etc.) but it didn't work. Just that comment alone changed the outcome of the run. I've seen the following but I haven't got a solution.
How to connect to MySQL databas using GitHub Actions?
Installing MySQL in Docker fails with error message "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"
Any help or offer would be appreciated.
[1] https://github.com/mirromutth/mysql-action
※ Finally, I added this in the file(test.yml) and resolved the problem.
- name: Wait for MySQL
    run: |
      while ! mysqladmin ping --host=127.0.0.1 -uroot -p1234 --silent; do
        sleep 1
      done


Looks to me like you're trying to connect to the MySQL container on localhost which is why it's trying to use a local socket. You didn't include your Spring DB credentials part so can't really tell

Have you seen this comment?

Thank you, I saw this answer and resolved it.
